# Her usual smile would flatten

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is "Her usual smile would flatten" natural in English? What does it mean? Does it mean "Her usual smile would disappear"?

> “I think the neighbours have it.” My mum was always conscious of her health. Nevertheless, the anxiety in her voice was jarring. Although we were talking by telephone, I could picture what she looked like. **Her usual smile would flatten**, transforming her face into an ashen mask. “I am scared. If I get it, I have no one. I am alone.”

> Source: [The Lancet](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(21)00155-0/fulltext)

Comment: Yes, it is natural. It is uncommon, though.

Comment: Agreed; it is an unusual phrasing, but the meaning is quite clear.

Comment: What does "a flatten smile" mean then?

Comment: @NewPlanet - A *flattened* smile would mean "a smile that has become flat".

Comment: @stangdon - Does "flat" mean "without emotion"?

Comment: @NewPlanet - It can mean "without emotion", but in this case you should read it more literally.  A smile is curved :-) but if it goes flat :-| then it is not a smile anymore, so she stopped smiling.